# Android/Kotlin read file using Java.io.File : path trouble

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, java-io

I am trying to develop my first app on android using Kotlin. For the moment I try to read a file located in my android project.
I have the following architecture under my "Java" folder :

```
/java/example.first.com.monapp/controller/FirstActivity.kt
/java/example.first.com.monapp/controller/WelcomeActivity.kt
/java/example.first.com.monapp/model/words.kt
/java/example.first.com.monapp/model/wordsData
```

wordsData is a text file with raw data (3 words per line separated by a ";")

The code in words.kt is :

```
package example.first.com.monapp.model

import java.io.File

data class Word(val wordFr:String, val wordRu:String, val active:Boolean)

fun readFileKotlin(): List<Word> {

    val fileToRead="wordsData"
    val wordList = mutableListOf<Word>()
    var reader= File(fileToRead).readLines()
    var wrdLst:List<Word>

    for (line in reader) {
        val wrdProperties = line.split(";")
        wordList.add(Word(wrdProperties[0], wrdProperties[1], wrdProperties[2].toBoolean()))
    }
    wrdLst=wordList
    return wrdLst
}
```

I call the readFileKotlin function during the creation of my activity but I continuously get the "java.io.FileNotFoundException" No such file or directory error.

I tried several variant to the path such as

```
val fileToRead="model/wordsData"
```

or

```
val fileToRead="/java/example.first.com.monapp/model/"
```

or

```
val fileToRead="/java/example/first/com/monapp/model/"
```

but none of this works.

What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put the wordsData file into the android `assets` folder, it is the folder where you can put raw data assets in android

Then in your Activity you can get an InputStream like this:

```
getAssets().open("wordsData.txt")
```